# Order of a group with given subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In particular i have the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ and i want to prove that if G is a group that contain both groups as subgroups, then $|G|$ is divisible by $p^{2n-1}$. I don't know if in general there is way to know the minimum size of a group with 2 given subgroups, but i couldn't find anything.
If G is abelian, then in this case the "minimum" group containing both would be $\mathbb{Z}_p^{n-1}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$, but if G is not abelian i am not sure.

Comment: Do you know this?:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems

Comment: @mcmat23 Yes i know the Sylow Theorems, but i dont know to which part are you refering exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim. If $G$ is a finite group that contains subgroups
$H\cong \mathbb Z_p^m$ and $K\cong Z_{p^n}$, then $|G|$
is a multiple of $p^{m+n-1}$.

Justification:

Let $P$ be a Sylow
$p$-subgroup of $G$. Since $H$ and $K$ are $p$-groups and
all $p$ subgroups of $G$ are conjugate to subgroups of $P$, there
exist $H', K'\leq P$ that are conjugate to $H$ and $K$.
Thus $P$ also contains subgroups isomorphic to
$Z_p^m$ and $Z_{p^n}$. If we prove that $p^{m+n-1}$
divides $|P|$ we will also get that $p^{m+n-1}$
divides $|P|[G:P] = |G|$.

Thus it suffices to consider only the case where $G=P$ is a $p$-group.

Choose and fix a group $P$ with subgroups $H$ and $K$ as above. Then

$$|P| \geq |HK| = \frac{|H| |K|}{|H\cap K|}\geq 
\frac{p^m\cdot p^n}{p} = p^{m+n-1}.$$

Since $|P|$ is a power of $p$ that is greater or equal to $p^{m+n-1}$, $|P|$ is divisible by $p^{m+n-1}$.

(The calculation depends on the fact that $|H\cap K|=1$ or $p$, which follows from the fact that $H\cap K$ is cyclic of exponent $p$.)

Comment: Thanks Keith, i was having problems with the intersection part... but now i get it. Btw i think this is true if i replace $p$ for any integer $r$, by doing the same argument for every prime on the prime decomposition of $r$, i'll check the details later, thank you again